# Change Multiple properties of same object

Tags: java

Is there any way in Java to achieve something like this:

```
    jPanel1.label1
        .setText("something")
        .setEnabled(something)
        .setVisible(something)
```

instead of typing the same variable name over and over again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Follow the [`builder pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to achieve what you want. Each method of it returns the same instance back after the modifications.

Directly pasting the example here :

```
public class StreetMap {
    private final Point origin;
    private final Point destination;

    private final Color waterColor;
    private final Color landColor;
    private final Color highTrafficColor;
    private final Color mediumTrafficColor;
    private final Color lowTrafficColor;

    public static class Builder {
        // Required parameters
        private final Point origin;
        private final Point destination;

        // Optional parameters - initialize with default values
        private Color waterColor         = Color.BLUE;
        private Color landColor          = new Color(30, 30, 30);
        private Color highTrafficColor   = Color.RED;
        private Color mediumTrafficColor = Color.YELLOW;
        private Color lowTrafficColor    = Color.GREEN;

        public Builder(Point origin, Point destination) {
            this.origin      = origin;
            this.destination = destination;
        }

        public Builder waterColor(Color color) {
            waterColor = color;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder landColor(Color color) {
            landColor = color;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder highTrafficColor(Color color) {
            highTrafficColor = color;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder mediumTrafficColor(Color color) {
            mediumTrafficColor = color;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder lowTrafficColor(Color color) {
            lowTrafficColor = color;
            return this;
        }

        public StreetMap build() {
            return new StreetMap(this);
        }

    }

    private StreetMap(Builder builder) {
        // Required parameters
        origin      = builder.origin;
        destination = builder.destination;

        // Optional parameters
        waterColor         = builder.waterColor;
        landColor          = builder.landColor;
        highTrafficColor   = builder.highTrafficColor;
        mediumTrafficColor = builder.mediumTrafficColor;
        lowTrafficColor    = builder.lowTrafficColor;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StreetMap map = new StreetMap.Builder(new Point(50, 50), new Point(100,
                100)).landColor(Color.GRAY).waterColor(Color.BLUE.brighter())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? Im new to Java

Comment: @YasithJayawardana Well, the link attached have a Java exmple. Wait, I'll paste it here

Comment: Yeah i got it! Thank you very much!